# Bash new line before getting results

Tags: macos, bash

I'm modifying my console colors and PS1 var on macos bash. So far I've got it right the way I want it. However, last thing I would like to have is new line AFTER command I input and BEFORE the result. Script for the moment looks like:

```
function parse_git_dirty {
  [[ $(git diff --shortstat 2> /dev/null | tail -n1) != "" ]] && echo " *"
}
function parse_git_branch {
  git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e "s/* \(.*\)/ (\1$(parse_git_dirty)\)/"
}

export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=exFxBxDxCxegedabagacex
export PS1="\n\[$(tput setaf 4)\]\u\[$(tput setaf 2)\] \h: \[$(tput setaf 0)\]\w\[$(tput setaf 4)\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$(tput sgr0)\] \$ "
```

Here is how it looks now

[image: Here is how it looks now]

I want it to look like

```
user host pwd (branch) $ ls
--- newline which is missing and I don't know how to get it here ---
folder folder file whatever.something etc...
--- newline that is here because of the \n in PS1 ---
user host pwd (branch) $
```

Additional description of behaviour:

- Newline is supposed to be there after I press enter to execute command.
- If the result of command has multiple lines, newline should only be displayed once (in example above, new line should only appear once after ls command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (ab)use the `DEBUG` trap to print an empty line just before each command executes. This might not be exactly what you want, but it's the closest thing `bash` provides.

```
$ trap 'echo' DEBUG
$ echo foo

foo
$ echo foo; echo bar

foo

bar
$
```

Note the DEBUG trap executes for each logical command, not once per command line.

Comment: This works, had to remove the new line from PS1 because otherwise I end up with 2 new lines at the end (guessing printing out PS1 is command as well). Noticing you wrote (ab)use, would it be possible to elaborate if this has any downsides (I don't intend to write more then one command per line). And note I have no idea what I'm doing here around bash :)

Comment: Mainly, I meant that the DEBUG trap isn't meant for this kind of output configuration; it's used to, for example, print the value of a variable after each command in a script executes so you can trace what is happening. I don't think anything *bad* would happen, but I can't guaranteed you won't end up with extraneous blank lines in the output of various complex shell commands.

Comment: One problem I have with this though is that I use bash in WebStorm as well. Keeping newline in PS1 variable prints double newline at the end of the result in terminal, but in WebStorm it doesn't print any newline if I don't have it in PS1

Comment: Also, I can't reproduce the extra newline you get at the end with your prompt.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/iXisYqz.png this is what I have now with 

export PS1="\[$(tput setaf 4)\]\u\[$(tput setaf 2)\] \h: \[$(tput setaf 0)\]\w\[$(tput setaf 4)\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$(tput sgr0)\] \$ "

trap 'echo' DEBUG

Comment: Tested on windows now, works as expected, PS1 still has the new line and I don't get the second one. Will play around with it tomorrow on work with Mac to see if I can get it to skip extra row that appears there.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you have to do is put a \n at the end of your export PS1 statement.

Like:

```
export PS1="\n\[$(tput setaf 4)\]\u\[$(tput setaf 2)\] \h: \[$(tput setaf 0)\]\w\[$(tput setaf 4)\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$(tput sgr0)\] \$\n"
```

But in that case you probably would want a character indicating where you are.  So you might do something like:

```
export PS1="\n\[$(tput setaf 4)\]\u\[$(tput setaf 2)\] \h: \[$(tput setaf 0)\]\w\[$(tput setaf 4)\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$(tput sgr0)\]\n\$ "
```

With a space after your $ character, to make it look nice.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I don't wanna split my input to new line. I have this kind of solution running on windows git bash because of some other limitations I have to figure out there, but that is not related to this question.

Comment: I wouldn't (ab)use DEBUG.  The newline character \n is what you need.